# Javascript creating object to display new information

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create 'customer' object that will store all of this data and then display the information as a ‘Customer Order' with listing all the new information. I guess it must be something like this.

```js
var objectarray=[];
var customer={ name,address,postalcode,phone,email}

function addToArray() {
 
 var customerobject={name,address,postalcode,phone,email};
 customerobject.name=document.getElementById("name").value;
 customerobject.address=document.getElementById("address").value;
 customerobject.postalcode=document.getElementById("postalcode").value;
 customerobject.phone=document.getElementById("phone").value;
 customerobject.email=document.getElementById("email").value;
 objectarray.push(customerobject);
 displayList();
 
}
```

However, the main problem for me is that I can't figure out how to store all of this data and then display the information as a ‘Customer Order' with listing all the new information.

Comment: `var customerobject={name,address,postalcode,phone,email};` is not valid object.It goes in key-value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var customerobject={name,address,postalcode,phone,email};
```

isn't correct. Actually you're just giving your objects the keys without a value.
This is how it should look like:

```
  var customerobject = {name: "",address: "",postalcode: "",phone: "",email: ""}
```

Here's an example based on your code:

```js
var objectarray = [];
function addToArray() {

  var customerobject = {
    name: "",
    address: "",
    postalcode: "",
    phone: "",
    email: ""
  }
  customerobject.name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  customerobject.address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  customerobject.postalcode = document.getElementById("postalcode").value;
  customerobject.phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  customerobject.email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  objectarray.push(customerobject);
  console.log(objectarray);

}
document.getElementById("clickMe").addEventListener("click", clicked);

function clicked() {
  addToArray();
}
```

```html
<input id="name" value="Gregory" />
<input id="address" value="Mapstreet" />
<input id="postalcode" value="56467454" />
<input id="phone" value="1234" />
<input id="email" value="me@myself.com" />
<button id="clickMe">click me</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! However, my main problem is that I can't figure out how to store all of this data and then display the information as a ‘Customer Order' with listing all the new information.

javascript

Comment: In a customer object that I will create.

Comment: As far as I can tell this is what the code is actually doing yet. Try it for yourself! Run the example and hit 'click me'. Afterwards fill in some different stuff into the input fields and hit 'click me' once more. If you look at the console you will notice that now there are two objects inside **objectarray** containing your customer information.